Target specific region of a webpage/url in a CDN (Content delivery Network)
I am trying to send a simple get request to site that is hosted in a CDN.
E.g. google.com, youtube.com, reddit.com, etc.
And compare its contents depending on its region (NA, EU, Asia, AUS,...)
When I send a request I will always get routed by the DNS to the next/fastest server in my region.
So when I am in Europe, I will probably end up sending the request to some edge server in Amsterdam, Frankfurth, Paris, etc...
When I am in Asia, the request will end up somewhere in Bejing, Seoul, Tokyo,...
Can I somehow, when sitting in Europe, send a request to google.com that ends up on a server in Asia or NorthAmerica? Is it as simple as forcing a regional DNS server, and if so is there a way in python to do that DNS?
Thanks!

did you try to rotate IP using proxy? or use a VPN? It all depends on your ISP so try to request like you're in Asia (from Europe) and this is only possible while using a VPN, proxy, or VPS server that is hosted in your target region. Also, try country domains like www.google.com.bd, www.google.co.in, www.google.com.hk, www.google.com.na
